# A question on polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Are there a real polynomial $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ such that $$\frac{1}{t^{20}-1}=\frac{a(t)}{t^2-1}+\frac{b(t)}{t^5-1}$$ hold for every real $t\neq \pm 1$?

Answer (score 5):

No.

If there were such polynomials, then the equation would hold for all complex $t$ as well.

The left hand side has 20 poles in the complex plane, counting multiplicity. However, the right hand side has at most 7 poles. So the two sides cannot be equal.

More explicitly, if $\zeta$ is a primitive $20$-th root of unity, the left hand side is singular at $\zeta$ but the right hand side is not.

Comment: If one is interested in exact statements, the right hand side actually has at most 6 poles, because both terms share the common factor $(t-1)$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying across gives $(t^5-1)(t^2-1) = (t^{20}-1)(a(t)(t^5-1)+b(t)(t^2-1))$.

If $p_1,p_2$ are two non-zero polynomials, then $\partial p_1 \cdot p_2 = \partial p_1 + \partial p_2$. If either $p_1$ or $p_2$ is zero, then clearly $p_1 \cdot p_2 = 0$.

Now let $p_1(t) = (t^{20}-1)$, $p_2(t) = a(t)(t^5-1)+b(t)(t^2-1)$. Hence the product is either $0$ or has degree $\partial p_1 \cdot p_2 \geq 20$. However the left hand side above has degree $7$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Degree 7, not 10.

Comment: @ErickWong: Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

By adding fractions, it is enough to show that no polynomial $c(t)$ satisfies $$\frac{1}{t^{20}-1} = \frac{c(t)}{(t^2-1)(t^5-1)},$$
equivalently $(t^{20}-1)\,c(t) = (t^2-1)\,(t^5-1)$.  This is trivially impossible by comparing degrees.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you multiply through by all denominators you get a seventh degree polynomial on the left hand side and as a factor you get a twentieth degree polynomial on the right. How does that balance?  In order to bring the right hand degree down to ten, the expressions for $a,b$ must not be polynomials.